# WMI shutting down. Events

Tags: .net, wmi

Is there a way to determine if remote machine is shutting down.  May be WMI subsystem sends some events in such cases before it shuts down, so I can subscribe to it?

I've seen sombody here discussing catching EventLog shutting down event, but the author wasn't sure at what point it actually shuts down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> May be WMI subsystem sends some events in such cases before it shuts down, so I can subscribe to it?

Yes, [`Win32_ComputerShutdownEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394101.aspx) is what you need.

Comment: Although, due to power failure remote computer might just shutdown.  I guess I'll have to ping that server periodically time to time.